# Creating Tables in Sphinx while sourcing from Markdown

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, tabular

I am creating my SphinX document via sourcing from a MarkDown source file i.e. in my `index.rst` file I have:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   myMarkDownText
.
.
.
```

in which `myMarkDownText` is refereeing to a `myMarkDownText.md`

I tried creating a table from this source MarkDown file in both following formats:

```
| Name            | Age   |
| :---            |  ---: |
| John D Hunter   | 40    |
```

where is in MD syntax, and

```
==================   ============
Name                 Age
==================   ============
John D Hunter        40
==================   ============
```

where is in RST syntax.

Non of them appear to produce a table-shape in my SphinX output `index.html` when I create it via:

```
make html
```

Do you know any other format/way that I should try?

PS_ Please notice, I *can* produce tables in good shape if I put my table in my `index.rst` in my SphinX. But this is not my question. My question is creating tables in SphinX while sourcing from `.md` source files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Table syntax is a non-standard extension to Markdown which is not supported by the implementation used by Sphinx. Therefore it appears to not be possible.

According to the [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/markdown.html), Sphinx  uses [recommonmark](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to parse Markdown documents, which is a [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) implementation of Markdown. As you can see in the CommonMark spec, tables are **not** a supported feature. For completeness, note that tables were also not part of the original [Markdown rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) either. Also, a review of the [options](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_structify.html) available in recommonmark indicate that there is no optional support for tables to be enabled.

Perhaps an alternate Markdown implementation exists with a docutils bridge, but I'm not aware of any myself (and recommending libraries is off topic here).

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [sphinx-markdown-tables](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-markdown-tables/) let you get your table in sphinx when sourcing from markdown using `recommonmark`.

The other solution is to put your table in a csv file and use the [native integration](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#id4) of csv files into RST format. If you source from markdown with `recommonmark` you can use the `eval_rst` option to get your rst snippet evaluated, [doc here](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_structify.html#embed-restructuredtext)

Solution 2 has the advantage of being built-in whereas solution 1 is easier once setup, as you don't have to deal with extra files and absolute/relative path issues